# button that helps you show an answer

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button

I'm trying to make a button where if the viewer types in an answer in the input field, they would get a

answer down that tells them if they were wrong or right. How do I do this?

```js
var SbnAnswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;

function SbnAnswer() {
  if (answer === "a map" || "map") {
    var answer = toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = "Congratulations, you answered right!";
  } else {
    (document.getElementById('wrong').innerHTML = "Your answer is wrong.");
  }
}
```

```html
<p>I have mountains - but no rocks, forest - but no trees, river - but no water. I'm here to help you. What am I?</p>
<input type="text" id="answer"> </button> <button id="SbnAnswer" type="button">Answer</button>
<p id="right" value="right"></p>
<p id="wrong" value="wrong"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do it

```js
function sbnAnswer () {
  
  var SbnAnswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
  SbnAnswer = SbnAnswer.toLowerCase();
  

    if (SbnAnswer === "a map" || SbnAnswer === "map") {
      
      document.getElementById('right').innerHTML="Congratulations, you answered right!";

    }

  else(document.getElementById('wrong').innerHTML="Your answer is wrong.");




    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="answer"> </button> <button id="SbnAnswer" type="button" onclick="sbnAnswer()">Answer</button>

 <p id="right" value="right"></p>

 <p id="wrong" value="wrong"></p>
```

Comment: Great it works. But do you know how to get UpperCase letters to LowerCase?

Comment: @EirikAndreasGustavsen Yes, please see update answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to do what you are looking for. I will try to simplify the code.

First you need to call a function upon the click of the button. The simple way of doing this is via the `onclick` attribute on you html button.

```
<button id="SbnAnswer" type="button" onclick="SbnAnswer()">Answer</button>
```

Once we have that, we can work on the function

First you need to get the value of the answer inside the function, not outside. This so the value updates every time the button is clicked.

```
var SbnAnswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
```

Then you can turn the answer into lower cases

```
var answer = SbnAnswer.toLowerCase();
```

I would recommend combining this two steps to get the next result

```
var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value.toLowerCase();
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
function SbnAnswer() {
  //var SbnAnswer = .value;
  var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value.toLowerCase();
  console.log(answer)
  
    if (answer === "a map" || answer === "map") {
    document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = "Congratulations, you answered right!";
  } else {
  document.getElementById('wrong').innerHTML = "Your answer is wrong.";
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="answer">
<button id="SbnAnswer" type="button" onclick="SbnAnswer()">Answer</button>

<p id="right" value="right"></p>

<p id="wrong" value="wrong"></p>
```

Comment: It gives me no output.

Comment: What are you putting in the input?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this.

You don't need two separate paragraphs for one answer, just use one and let `js` fill its text based on the answer using `.textContent` method.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#SbnAnswer');
const input = document.querySelector('#answer');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const answer = input.value.toLowerCase();
  if (answer === 'a map' || answer === 'map') {
    output.textContent = 'Congratulations, you answered right!';
  } else {
    output.textContent = 'Your answer is wrong.';
  }
});
```

```html
<p>I have mountains - but no rocks, forest - but no trees, river - but no water. I'm here to help you. What am I?</p>
<input type="text" id="answer" />
<button id="SbnAnswer">submit</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @EirikAndreasGustavsen Well, as you can see for yourself, it works here in the snippet so all you have to do is to copy it as it is. You get that error because you are missing element with id `'#SbnAnswer'` in your code.

Comment: I dont understand I've copied and pasted everything in ur HTML and JS. It doesnt work, but it works on the snippet. What do you mean Im missing an element with id '#SbnAnswer"? I've "written <button id="SbnAnswer">submit</button>" in my HTML

Comment: I mean that `document.querySelector('#button')` probably returns `null` instead of button element. Try `console.log(btn)` to see if the output is not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="ans" />
<button id="btn"></button>
```

Now you can add event listener

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() { 
var val = document.getElementById('ans').value; 
// do your checks now
}):
```